EU Visa Information System Data Record
Recently a friend had a bad experience entering one of the Schengen states, Norway. He was allowed entry as a tourist however the border guard made a reference to him making an adverse  entry into the system. ( Related to visa vs port of entry. )
We were curious whether this was a bluff or a entry was made and what it says.
One way I can think of is to make a open data FOIA request on the VIS ( eg the link below)  Only question is would the request itself be viewed adversely for future visas etc? Do visa officers etc get told that a VIS data request was made?
https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-information-system_en#:~:text=Any%20person%20has%20the%20right,personal%20data%20by%20that%20country.

The VIS can only contain information in a restricted list, and as far as I know looking up data in it isn’t in the list. It would also be quite contrary to GDPR.

There is also the Schengen Information System (SIS).

Thanks. So what's the difference between the SIS and the VIS? Are one or both outside the purview of a FOIA request?
